# What is bad about a witch being born in May?

Tags: harry-potter

One of the wizard superstitions that Ron mentions when discussing the Tale of the Three Brothers is that:

> May-born witches will marry Muggles.

I'm speculating here but the whole culture of the wizards is anti-Muggle or at least promotes minimal contact with Muggles. This means that being born in May is considered a bad thing for witches.

Why is that?

Comment: It's a superstition.  Being born in May is bad for the same reason that Friday the 13th is unlucky.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus there are several theories about why is Friday the 13th considered unlucky although nothing is conclusive. See http://mentalfloss.com/article/52696/why-friday-13th-considered-unlucky.

Comment: I mean can't you imagine why? J Rowling isn't the most concerned person with continuity, I know she will just make stuff up on the spot, so there might be something about it, but can't you just imagine how that saying started? her works are very much about that, much is left to the reader. Imo such questions are the opposite of how one should go about reading the books

Comment: There's no good reason here to assume that it's a *bad* superstition. It's just pointing out something that happens more often (in opinion of whoever came up with the superstition).

Comment: @Valorum technically you are right. In practice however superstitions "warn" one about bad thing B happening if you do A.

Answer (score 4):

### It's a superstition. Its significance depends on who you ask.

Firstly, the statement is a superstition which is probably groundless. Ron doesn't seem to set much store by it and merely lists it as "one of those superstitions".

> “One of those superstitions, isn’t it? ‘May-born witches will marry Muggles.’ ‘Jinx by twilight, undone by midnight.’ ‘Wand of elder, never prosper.’ You must’ve heard them. My mum’s full of them.”
>   <sub>*(Deathly Hallows, Chapter 21, The Tale of the Three Brothers)*.</sub>

Indeed, Ron seems to dismiss these statements as meaningless slogans that have built up in wizarding communities over the years, just as he believes The Tale of the Three Brothers was developed to drill lessons into children.

> “You don’t believe it either?” Harry asked him.
>   “Nah, that story’s just one of those things you tell kids to teach them lessons, isn’t it? ‘Don’t go looking for trouble, don’t pick fights, don’t go messing around with stuff that’s best left alone! Just keep your head down, mind your own business, and you’ll be okay’."
>   <sub>*(Deathly Hallows, Chapter 21, The Tale of the Three Brothers)*.</sub>

It's therefore likely that May-born witches are no more likely to marry Muggles than anybody else.

Secondly, why would it be considered a negative statement? Well, it wouldn't be seen negatively by everyone. As Valorum says, the statement itself doesn't make a value judgement on whether marrying Muggles is a good or a bad thing.

For me, the question displays some circular logic in this regard. May-born witches marry Muggles, marrying Muggles is bad, therefore being born in May is unlucky. This logic is built on the premise that "the whole culture of the wizards is anti-Muggle". Yet this isn't the case. Who's to say that marrying Muggles is a bad thing? Certainly not the Weasleys, or any number of other 'blood traitors' (wizards who accept Muggle-borns) within the wizarding community. Of course, some people are anti-Muggle. Fanatical Purebloods like the Malfoys may think that being born in May is unlucky for a girl as a result (if they set any store by the superstition in the first place), but that's not to say that anyone else will.

The bottom line is that part of the wizarding community is pro-Muggle (and pro-Muggle-borns) and some of it is anti-Muggle (and anti-Muggle-borns). The people who think that being born in May is unlucky will therefore be the people who were anti-Muggle to begin with.